# How to flatten clothing for product shoot?

Tags: product-photography

I'm trying to emulate some of the non-model product photography on the adidas website.  I'm assuming its flat-lay but in a lot of cases it looks hung with a bit of movement visible.

Lines are very straight and shoulders of the products always look very clean and angled as if they are on some sort of hanger.

Any ideas on technique to achieve something similar?

[image]

Comment: They could have a board inside (with a neck area cut outside so you can't see it) to stretch out the shoulders and then pulled tight and fastened behind. This would explain the rather rectangular shape of the body.

Comment: Could you please edit your title to be descriptive of your question? (Imagine how many questions on this site — or on all of Stack Exchange! — that could be titled "How is this being done?"!!!)

Answer (score 2):

It could have been laid flat and arranged nicely, but to me it looks like it was hung on a coat hanger against a white surface and then a designer simply photoshopped the image a bit.

I'm a graphic designer and used to work for an online retailer taking and editing their product images.  You get all kinds of creative, when doing these things.  You can see how nicely a hanger fits with the soulders.  The way the jacket's collar is sitting, the strings, light/shadows...they all lead me to believe the jacket was hung vertically and not laid down.

As for the sleeves, they could have been pinned/taped to the wall, held in place by an assistant, propped with foam board, etc. We'll never really know.

[image]

Comment: I did think there was a hanger in there somewhere, especially with the angles at the edges of the hood at the inside, just have never been able to  get it similar, even with pins tape and all sorts of other wacky stuff.  Thanks !

Comment: They could have a rectangular frame attached to the wall via a central connector. It would be easy enough to cut holes in the back of the items to fit them on the frame. I'm sure Adidas has a large enough budget that they can just cut holes in the back of items to fit them over the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The jacket may be on an angled surface, with a board on the inside. If you notice the pull strings and the sleeves appear to be slightly hanging. The shot does not appear made on a flat (horizontal) surface or vertical surface.

Comment: I do use a board on the inside with the stuff i do, but have always laid it flat and looks a bit "lifeless" - never been able to get it anywhere near right hanging on a wall.  Didn't even consider an angle inbetween.  Will give it a shot on an angled board maybe with a hanger shaping the top as suggested above and some pins keep things in place.  Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

try using pin or needles on the shoulders on cardboard standing up